# Advantages of these recommendations in ooprogramming using Java

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented, interfaces

Below are the recommendation from section 5.1 of this [essay](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf).

> While Java is not a pure object-oriented language, it is possible to program in a pure object-oriented style by obeying the following rules:
>
> 1) **Classes only as constructors** A class name may only be used after the keyword `new`.
>
> 2) **No primitive equality** The program must not use primitive equality (==). Primitive equality exposes representation and prevents simulation of one object by another.
>
> 3) In particular, classes may not be used as **types** to declare **members**, **method arguments** or **return values**. Only **interfaces** may be used as **types**. Also, classes may not be used in **casts** or to test with `instanceof`.
>
> This is generally considered good object-oriented style

For instance,

below part of jdk code does not follow third point mentioned above:

return type of `toArray` method.

```
public Object[] toArray() {
     //whatever
   }
```

in `java.util.AbstractCollection`.

or

return type of `toString()` nethod.

```
public String toString() {
        //whatever
    }
```

below part of jdk code does follow third point above:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    }
```

What advantages do we find in following these recommendation? Can some design patterns be pulled in(automatically), by following such recommendations?

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the essay (after reading all the others).

Comment: The advantage of following these recommendations is that we satisfy the vanity of some hard core purists of object orientation who are very good at theorizing about things but who have never really written any actual, non-trivial, real world application.  Sort of like the guy who was told sunbathing is inadvisable because prolonged exposure to the sun is bad for you, and so he never leaves home during daylight.

Comment: This should be closed because it's too broad. If the answer to this question can be a book's chapter about OOP design practices, then it's probably not for this site. This question will either invite subjective opinion, or will result in long-winded answers where you will be inclined to debate with the author.

Comment: @AndresF. Do you recommend some resource(book) to get an answer for this question?

Comment: @overexchange Any book on OO design and programming will probably do.

Answer (score 3):

What you gain by following his recommendations is the ability to accept any object regardless of implementation as long as it implements an interface correctly. There's nothing special about this and it's a commonly-used technique. As the paper points out, what you lose is:

1. The ability to restrict variables to a specific class, which matters when correctness is important. For example, if Java's SecurityManager accepted the `CharSequence` interface instead of the `String` class, you could subvert its security checks by passing in a mutable string.
2. The ability for methods to look at the implementation details of two objects. For instance the `Set` interface can't have a reasonable set union method because there's no guarantee two `Set`s have the same implementation. The only way to calculate the union of two `Set`s is the naive, inefficient way - iterate through both of them.

Comment: `CharSequence` author does not allow to use it in place of immutable`class String`, as contract says, "The result of comparing two objects that implement `CharSequence` is therefore, in general, undefined."

Comment: @overexchange Someone trying to subvert Java's security manager doesn't care what the `CharSequence` contract says.

Answer (score 0):

My humble opinion is that this kind of bold statements can be wrong,  boldly.

1. Will not be possible to use a static class. And won't allow some ways of creating a singleton for instance.
2. Sometimes it is useful and helps the algorithm. But read this post  it will help you make up your own decision. http://cubussapiens.hu/2012/05/java-primitive-type-comparison-a-wat-look/
3. Classes are ok in a lot cases. Interfaces are good if you think you will be replacing the implementation of a class and also interfaces allow you to do dependency injection which helps unit testing. So I don't agree with 3 either.